# SolrCloud Configset API upload returns 500 "KeeperErrorCode = NoNode"

Tags: powershell, solrcloud

### Situation

First of all I must mention that I'm using Solr 8.1.1 and am running the default "solr -e cloud" to do some testing. This is running on a Windows Azure VM. I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that will do some setup on the SolrCloud. The first step in this is uploading a custom Configset. I was using https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/configsets-api.html as guide and the PowerShell command if you take away all the parameters and such boils down to the following:

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/configs?action=UPLOAD&name=MyConfig" -Method Post -ContentType "application/octet-stream" -InFile "config.zip"`

EDIT: For clarity the contents of the ZIP is as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49huS.jpg

### Problem

When I run the above command however I'm met with the following error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : { "responseHeader":{ "status":500, "QTime":11}, "error":{ "msg":"KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /configs/MyConfig/lang/contractions_ca.txt", "trace":"org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: 
KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /configs/MyConfig/lang/contractions_ca.txt\r\n\tat org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:114)\r\n\tat 
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)\r\n\tat org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:792)\r\n\tat 
org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.lambda$create$7(SolrZkClient.java:415)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.retryOperation(ZkCmdExecutor.java:71)\r\n\tat 
org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.create(SolrZkClient.java:415)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ConfigSetsHandler.createZkNodeIfNotExistsAndSetData(ConfigSetsHandler.java:201)\r\n\tat 
org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ConfigSetsHandler.handleConfigUploadRequest(ConfigSetsHandler.java:181)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ConfigSetsHandler.handleRequestBody(ConfigSetsHandler.java:111)\r\n\tat 
org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:796)\r\n\tat 
org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:762)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:522)\r\n\tat 
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:397)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:343)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n", 
"code":500}}
At line:1 char:1
```

### Observations

When I first "failed" I had created a zip file from my config which contained an additional top level folder (ea instead of MyConfig/solrconfig.xml etc my ZIP was MyConfig/MyConfig/solrconfig.xml) and when I used this the command was run successful but the second command (creating a collection) would fail because it could not find solrconfig.xml. This tells me that the ZIP is correctly present in the request and Solr does seem capable of processing it but once I correct it to an actual configset it massively fails?

EDIT: I was asked about this and whether using "conf" in the zip would work. As I mentioned here this results in a successful upload (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNrkE.jpg) however as you can see it does not match the other config sets and when you try to create a collection with this set you will get `Error CREATEing SolrCore 'Test_shard1_replica_n1': Unable to create core [Test_shard1_replica_n1] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/Sitecore', cwd=C:\solr-8.1.1\server`

### Question(s)

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug?

Comment: I'm no ZooKeeper (or Solr) expert, but from the error alone it sounds like it's expecting you to provide a `contractions_ca.txt` file as part of the config set?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this file is effectively in the ZIP I'm uploading so it's not missing, rather Solr seems unable to create it while unpacking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going back through some work I did on SolrCloud a while ago, I am reminded of one annoying issue I hit:

I got odd issues uploading the schema config zip files if I had created that zip using "Send to Compressed Folder" in the Windows UI, or via `Compress-Archive` in PowerShell. I found that compressing the data with 7Zip did work, however.

I suspect there's something incompatible between the Windows zip code (which I think is quite old, and something they licensed ages ago?) and how Solr/ZooKeeper deals with extracting the files again?

Comment: This was indeed the culprit! The ZIP was created using windows' "Send to Compressed Folder". Using a ZIP created by 7zip for example works without issue!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue without using Windows zip code.  I was trying to upload a configset to Solr 7.7.3 from a conf directory containing a "lang" subdirectory with a bunch of files. I got the NoNode error for `/configs/_myconfigsetname_/lang/stopwords_eu.txt`. The configset was being zipped on the fly through a recursive directory walk in Java, sending each filename to the Zip file using Java's ZipOutputStream.   The resulting zipped bytes were then sent to Solr/Zookeeper.

This code worked fine for conf directories without subdirectories.  It turned out that when there is a subdirectory, it was necessary to create a ZipEntry for the directory (*e.g.* `lang/`) before adding files to the Zip stream such as `lang/stopwords_eu.txt`.